# 2 decimals in function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do i write to get to decimals in the line with results? It calculates right but I want 2 decimals as the result.

```
<script>
            function divideBy() 
            { 
                    num1 = document.getElementById("odds").value;
                    num2 = document.getElementById("gameNumber").value;
                    num3 = document.getElementById("standardBet").value;
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ((num3 * num2)*1.9) / num1;
            }
 </script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round to at most 2 decimal places, if necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/how-to-round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-if-necessary)

Comment: @EliasSoares did you test that?

Comment: No, I was mixing PHP with JS. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
(((num3 * num2)*1.9) / num1).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: How does that matter